# How to write a simple java program which can convert series of time in single units? (For example in milliseconds)

Tags: java, excel, datetime, timestamp

I have series of a timestamp in an excel file (column wise) and some of the examples are below:

```
30m1.566s 
30m0.706s 
30m34.197s
30m1.545s
30m1.148s
30m1.791s
30m1.903
```

I want to convert these times to a single unit that is - milliseconds (e.g 30m1.903s time to all in milliseconds). Removing each 'm' and 's' would be very hard as there are 100s of timestamp so I was just trying to write a program in java or c to use the file to convert all the time in milliseconds but couldn't able to do it.

I would really appreciate any amount of help and suggestion please. Thank you so much.

[Larger data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Djpfp.png)

Comment: Do they all match `[0-9]+m[0-9]+\.[0-9]+s`?

Comment: Yes seems like the pattern is matching.

Answer (score 1):

Those are not timestamps - not in the sense that they represent a specific moment. Actually, they are durations - an amount of time.

One alternative is to transform the strings to [ISO8601 compliant format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) and parse them with `java.time.Duration`:

```
String s = "30m1.791s";
s = "PT" + s.replace("m", "M").replace("s", "S");
Duration duration = Duration.parse(s);
System.out.println(duration.toMillis()); // 1801791
```

Comment: Nice answer, thanks. `Duration.parse` parses case insensitively, so you don’t need `replace`. In other words `s = "PT" + s;` suffices.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

## Code [[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZDLasMwEEXX8VcMWUkJGZyGGkLoB3QRKGSZZKHaqitXL6RxaCn5dnfyMN1FCHRndC53pE6d1CJE7bvmaz0MxsWQCDruYk/GYtKt/sbZpqityhm2ynj4LSaxf7emhkyK@DgF04DjK7GjZHyLiKBSmyWjxWTypoh08hDhBe4a6@CisVpMxb5crI9z6UZxOOAo81Ru2L9VVH/qBI79Ed2tEpeAfXlkghGHH8Y34orzNp7AGd@Tzux59cSvSBhVypoL4bBNoY9iKa@GC511HXzzkH76p52x1jyEV/I22O4nk3YYesLIX0PWCzFONoOq5CVhDmLMn8Hy3rplXCLPxXkYhlXplvhcVfkP)]

```
import java.util.regex.*;
class Main {
    public static void main(String... args) {

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([0-9]+)m([0-9]+)\\.([0-9]+)s");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(args[0]);

        m.find();

        int minutes = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));
        int seconds = Integer.parseInt(m.group(2));
        int millis = Integer.parseInt(m.group(3));

        System.out.println((minutes * 60000) + (seconds * 1000) + millis);
    }
}
```

## Explanation

This uses the regex above to find the 3 parts, converts them to ints then adds them up

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works for one argument but how do I pass the whole excel or column of data (as attached screenshot in question - Larger data set) file having all these time in one column. Thanks again.

Comment: You'd need to go into parsing and writing excel files, which would be a different question, [this](https://www.mkyong.com/java/apache-poi-reading-and-writing-excel-file-in-java/) may be of use